# Binding datasource to application when using springBootApplication in Liberty?

Tags: spring-boot, open-liberty

When deploying "regular" web apps to Liberty, I was used to binding the global datasource configured in Liberty's server.xml to the individual application by using a child element within the  element, like this:

```
   <application context-root="helloApp" location="..." name="helloApp" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
             <data-source id="db2appDs" name="jdbc/datasource" binding-name="jdbc/theDB"/>
        </application-bnd>
        ...
    </application>
    <dataSource id="db2ds" jndiName="jdbc/theDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource">        
        ...
    </dataSource>
```

When configuring my first Spring Boot application to deploy to Liberty, I am trying to use the new `<springBootApplication>` element for it - but I don't seem to be able to add a binding for the datasource I want to use the same way, as this element doesn't seem to support such a child.  (It seems to want only `<classloader>` as a child).
I've seen people suggest I use an `@Resource` annotation that includes both application-local JDNI name and global JNDI name for the datasorce - but that defeats the purpose, since I don't want to know what the global name is until deploy time.

Is there another way to do this, like we used to before?  Or are applications deployed through `<springBootApplication>` expected to know the global JNDI name of the datasource(s) they want?

Answer (score 0):

Application-defined datasources are not supported for `<springBootApplication/>`’s.  While your application may certainly access a Liberty datasource using its global JNDI name, you should configure the `spring.datasource.jndi-name` property within your Spring Boot application as described in [section 29.1.3 of the Spring Boot features reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html).  For your example try `spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/theDB`.